# how to separate each script in diferent files in Flyway?

Tags: java, database, version-control, flyway

I'm trying to put my data base in version control with Flyway,
and **I want to put the script for each procedure, function, table etc. in separated files and subfolders**, like this:

[image]

but I'm getting this error:

```
    org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found more than one migration with version 1.0
Offenders:
-> C:\...\target\classes\db\migration\views\asuntoConsultar\V1.0__asuntoConsultar.sql (SQL)
-> C:\...\target\classes\db\migration\tables\asuntos\V1.0__asuntos.sql (SQL)
```

*is there a way to configure flyway to understand this structure?*

Answer (score 1):

Flyway can use this directory structure. You need to ensure that the version numbers for the scripts are unique across *all* directories. This is because Flyway searches the locations parameter for all scripts then determines the order to run them based on the version number. Running with debug turned on can help you see how this operates.

You may also need to investigate the OutOfOrder option so that you don't have to keep track of version numbers across folders as closely.

Comment: @AlfredoM Let me emphasize the point here that your are abusing the version numbering system of Flyway. There must *not* be multiple files with `V1.0__` in the name (by default). **Nesting folders is irrelevant** to Flyway by default. First thing Flyway does is gather up all the scripts found in any of the possible places it looks, including within nested folders. Second to that, Flyway parses the name of each file to create a *major.minor.micro.nano* style of number commonly used in the software industry. That version number determines the order of execution of scripts, by default.

Comment: @BasilBourque, the original poster is able to use their folder structure as long as the file version numbers are unique.

Comment: Uhhh, yes — that is the point I was trying to emphasize. The original poster is thinking in terms of the folder hierarchy being meaningful. You and I are both trying to re-orient that thinking to **focus on version numbers, not folders**.

Comment: Agreed. Putting repeatable migrations into different folders may be enough.